# How to get params in routing MERN?

Tags: reactjs, express, parameters, routes

After setting up dynamic routing, I've been having a lot of trouble trying to get an item from MongoDB by ID. The URL is set up like:

```
http://localhost:3000/paprogram/:_id`
http://localhost:3000/paprogram/60bfbf12f8d33aef9ae4ebb9`
```

I am trying to get the _id from params so that I can use it to find the specific data in the database. It works perfectly fine as hardcoded below. But what is the proper req call to get the _id?

PaProgramsDetailsRouter.js:

```
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // get school by id
    const PaProgramDetail = await PaProgram.find({
      _id: '60bfbf12f8d33aef9ae4ebb9',
      //_id: req.params._id,
      // id: req.this.props.match.params._id,
    });
    res.json(PaProgramDetail);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send();
  }
});
```

this is how paProgramDetailRouter route is set up in index.js:

```
app.use('/paprogram/:_id', require('./routers/paProgramDetailsRouter'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
req.params._id
```

Comment: I tried that one and it didn't work. Printing it through the console and it says "undefined".

Comment: What gets returned from req? because this should work

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: when I use console.log(req.originalUrl), it returns "/paprogram/:_id/" instead of "/paprogram/60bfbf12f8d33aef9ae4ebb9".